# Cakephp i18n - Constructor failed - Intl Exception

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, intl, po

I recently extracted strings from the app I'm building with Cakephp thanks to their awesome i18n Shell. 
I then made a translation (from French to English) and put the files in src/Locale:

```
src/
    Locale/
        default.po 
        fr/
            default.po
```

The first default.po in the Locale/ folder is formatted as follow:

```
msgid "View"
msgstr ""
```

The default.po in the fr/ folder:

```
msgid "View"
msgstr "Vue"
```

In my App Controller, I want to test the traduction:

```
public function initialize()
{
      parent::initialize();
      I18n::locale('fr');
      ...
}
```

But I get the following error:

[image: Error Constructor failed Intl Exception]

I tried to look up for information on the web but couldn't find anything. I tried on several machine as well.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks folks !

**EDIT**:

Cake version is 3.3.12

Debug kit version is 3.3.12

Error.log :

```
2017-03-14 17:18:54 Error: [IntlException] Constructor failed
Request URL: /
Stack Trace:
#0 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php(89): MessageFormatter->__construct('fr', '{0, number, #, ...') 
#1 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php(52): Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter->_formatMessage('fr', '{0, number, #, ...', Array)
#2 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Translator.php(150): Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter->format('fr', '{0, number, #, ...', Array)
#3 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php(84): Cake\I18n\Translator->translate('{0,number,#,###...', Array)
#4 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/Number.php(92): __d('cake', '{0,number,#,###...', 2.2256164550781)
#5 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Panel/TimerPanel.php(125): Cake\I18n\Number::toReadableSize(2333728)
#6 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/ToolbarService.php(191): DebugKit\Panel\TimerPanel->summary()
#7 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Routing/Filter/DebugBarFilter.php(139): DebugKit\ToolbarService->saveData(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#8 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(426): DebugKit\Routing\Filter\DebugBarFilter->afterDispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event), Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#9 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(391): Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener(Array, Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#10 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php(78): Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#11 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(100): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatchEvent('Dispatcher.afte...', Array)
#12 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(83): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#13 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(62): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#15 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#16 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#17 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#18 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(81): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#19 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#20 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#21 /www/fitadmin/admin/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(90): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#22 /www/fitadmin/admin/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#23 {main}
```

Comment: Did you add this `use Cake\I18n\I18n;` line top of the controller ? and also your local code may wrong. it would be `br_FR`

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), as you can see debug kit is somehow involved. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`), and in this case the debug kit version too (`vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: @tarikul05 yes I added use `Cake\I18n\I18n`. And I'm not sure about the bf_FR, take a look at this example from the core cakephp locale folder :[link](https://github.com/cakephp/localized/tree/master/src/Locale))

Comment: @ndm yep sorry about this ! I edited my post :-)

Comment: In case this isn't a quirks in the output, the formatting pattern changes in `Cake\I18n\Translator::translate()`, the spaces in there are invalid (`{0, number, #, ...`). Have you added translations for these number patterns? Either in your `default.po` files, or in other possibly existing message files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @ndm's comment I looked inside my .po file and tried to remove the translations from the cakephp vendor folder. I noticed there was some absolute paths (C: /xampp/...) that weren't supposed to be there.

That did the trick...

Answer (score 2):

**For reference:** 
I had the same problem and it turned out to be a syntax error in my .po file. In my case:

```
msgid "My name is {0}"
msgstr "Jag heter {}"
```

Note the invalid placeholder `{}` in the translated string, which should of course be `{0}`.